# Path pattern matching /

Tags: restkit, dropbox-api, sockit

I'm trying to build a response descriptor for calls to the [Dropbox metadata API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#metadata).

Using the DBMetadata class from the [Dropbox OS X SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/osx), here is my mapping:

```
RKObjectMapping *metadataMapping;
metadataMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[DBMetadata class]];
[metadataMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"thumb_exists": @"thumbnailExists",
                                                      @"bytes"       : @"totalBytes",
                                                      @"modified"    : @"lastModifiedDate",
                                                      @"client_mtime": @"clientMtime",
                                                      @"path"        : @"path",
                                                      @"is_dir"      : @"isDirectory",
                                                      @"hash"        : @"hash",
                                                      @"size"        : @"humanReadableSize",
                                                      @"root"        : @"root",
                                                      @"icon"        : @"icon",
                                                      @"rev"         : @"rev",
                                                      @"revision"    : @"revision",
                                                      @"is_deleted"  : @"isDeleted"}];
[metadataMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"contents"
                                                 mapping:metadataMapping];
```

Here is my Response Descriptor (As much as I'd like to, I can't use :root:path, see [NOTE 1](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKPathMatcher.html#//api/name/pathMatcherWithPattern%3a)):

```
RKResponseDescriptor *metadataResponse;
metadataResponse = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:metadataMapping
                                                                method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                           pathPattern:@"metadata/dropbox:path"
                                                               keyPath:nil
                                                           statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
[self.manager addResponseDescriptor:metadataResponse];
```

The manager is setup as:

```
NSURL *baseAPIURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@://%@/%@/", kDBProtocolHTTPS, kDBDropboxAPIHost, kDBDropboxAPIVersion]];
self.manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:baseAPIURL];
self.manager.requestSerializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;
```

The problem is that the `@"metadata/dropbox:path"` path pattern always fails:

```
DBMetadata *root;
root = [[DBMetadata alloc] initWithDictionary:@{@"root": @"dropbox",
                                                @"path": @"/"}];
[self.manager getObject:root
                   path:@"metadata/dropbox/"
             parameters:@{@"list": @"false"}
                success:...
                failure:...];
```

Result:

> E restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:213 GET
>   'https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/dropbox/?list=false' (200 OK / 0
>   objects) [request=0.0957s mapping=0.0000s total=0.0968s]: Error
>   Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=1001 "No response
>   descriptors match the response loaded." UserInfo=0x6000000ee900
>   {NSLocalizedFailureReason=A 200 response was loaded from the URL
>   'https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/dropbox/?list=false', which failed
>   to match all (0) response descriptors:,
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/dropbox/?list=false,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/dropbox/?list=false,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x6000000569b0 "No mappable object representations
>   were found at the key paths searched.", keyPath=null,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=No response descriptors match the response
>   loaded.}

But if I set the path pattern in the response descriptor to a static string (`@"metadata/dropbox/"`), it works:

> I restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:220 GET
>   'https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/dropbox/?list=false' (200 OK / 1
>   objects) [request=0.1027s mapping=0.0014s total=0.1034s]

Is it not possible to pass "/" as a path pattern parameter?

I also noticed that the error says that the response *failed to match all **(0)** response descriptors*. Shouldn't it be (1) in this case?

Comment: Did you try `@"metadata/dropbox/:path"` ?

Comment: Yes. Same result: "failed to match all (0) response descriptors"

Comment: I'd say it's actually a good thing it doesn't work, or there would be a lot of response descriptor clashes. I'd think about just using multiple response descriptors with different path patterns.

Comment: Apparently you can't use a slash like this.

See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16690770/rkroute-with-as-parameter-doesnt-work